# Optimize table on large table online DDL Feature

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6, online-operations

I am running optimize table on MySQL table size 340GB in size and storage engine is InnoDB.

```
mysql> show variables like '%tmp%';
+----------------------------+------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value            |
+----------------------------+------------------+
| default_tmp_storage_engine | InnoDB           |
| innodb_tmpdir              |                  |
| max_tmp_tables             | 32               |
| slave_load_tmpdir          | /dbtmp/mysql_tmp |
| tmp_table_size             | 33554432         |
| tmpdir                     | /dbtmp/mysql_tmp |
```

tmpdir directory is filling up space .

```
/dev/mapper/vgdbtmp-lvdbtmp
                      296G  231G   51G  83% /dbtmp
```

What will be the alternate solution to optimize table without creating copy of table.

MySQL 5.6 version

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.6.46-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have read below MySQL link.

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-6-17-improved-online-optimize-table-for-innodb-and-partitioned-innodb-tables/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html

`Prior to Mysql 5.6.17, OPTIMIZE TABLE does not use online DDL. Consequently, concurrent DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) is not permitted on a table while OPTIMIZE TABLE is running, and secondary indexes are not created as efficiently.`

But here no one is firing DDL/DML/select on table currently.

It should run online without creating copy of table right?

Answer (score 1):

- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost useless for InnoDB.  Why are you running it?
- Some people like to break up the disk into partitions.  But that leads to overflowing one partition when there is spare room in another.  You *could* move tmpdir to a bigger partition?
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` table must copy the table over.  Ditto for flavors of `ALTER TABLE`.  Hence, you must have enough spare disp space, *preferrable in the same FS*, as the table.
- MySQL 8.0 has some "inline" or "in place" `ALTERs`; maybe it would help here.
- Percona's `pt-online-schema-change` avoids blocking writes during schema changes.  Ditto for `gh-ost`.  These probably need the extas disk space, so may not be relevant.

Moral of this story...  Don't let the disk get so full that you can't make a full copy of the biggest table.